# WAMP : PHP Curl "working" but returning empty string, file_get_contents is working

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I am running PHP Wampserver 3.2.6 under Windows 11 with Avast Antirus Free edition.

And PHP Version 8.1.0.

Now I have setup a simple curl script to fetch data from a remote host. But this returns nothing.
When I put the entire thing online on a server it works just fine. But from a local machine it doesn't work.

I have tried running the entire thing under postman. And there it works just fine.

```
private function __curl($url, $decode = true){
    // * create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();
    // * set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_url.$url);

    // * return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // * set headers
    $headers = array('X-IM-API-KEY: '.$this->api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


    // * if any postdata set
    if(!empty($this->postdata)){
        // * initialize post
        $this->__post();

        // * set postdata
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POST,       count($this->postdata));
        curl_setopt($ch,    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->postfieldstr);
    }


    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    // * if no decode
    if(!$decode) return $output;

    // * return result
    return json_decode($output, true);
    }
```

When I just use file_get_contents it works fine.

```
file_get_contents($this->api_url.$url);
```

The result :

> {"success":false,"error":true,"message":"fields
> missing","data":{"email":"not set","password":"not
> set","app_version":"1.1"}}

Of course it will give an error because it expects POST parameters with the username and password.

I have the following configuration visible under PHPinfo :

[image: PHP Info CURL configuration]

I hope someone can tell me what my mistake would be.

**EDIT**

When I add :

```
curl_error($ch);
```

I get the following error :

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

But when viewing the address in FireFox I get no error at all.
(letscrypt)

[image]

**EDIT : Answer added by : @codenathan**

---

Adding the following code to disable host and peer verification does the trick actually.

I think in combination with the local firewall the letscrypt certificate simply didn't get through in the way it was supposed to.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Since I need this for developement purposes this actually does the trick for me.

Comment: Run `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` between the exec and the close.

Comment: Try adding : curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: Although my answer above will work it's not ideal to turn it off: https://www.saotn.org/dont-turn-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-fix-php-configuration/

Comment: @codenathan Actually it works indeed! Thank you! I think in combination with a Windows environment + Firewall the letscrypt certificate does not get through..

Comment: sounds like a CURLOPT_CAPATH / openssl.cafile / https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html  issue

Comment: @codenathan can you add your comment as a post? So I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

However it is not ideal to switch this off : https://www.saotn.org/dont-turn-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-fix-php-configuration/